# Move an App Service to another storage account

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-function-app, azure-appservice

I have a lot of app services on alot of different storage accounts. I would like to consolidate some. Can you move function apps and app services to new storage accounts? I have not found anything in the admin UI.

Comment: An App Service doesn't *run on* a storage account, it *connects to* a storage account. Which means you can simply switch connection strings. You *should*, however, think about migrating data as well.

Comment: Thanks appreciated. Why do you select a storage account when creating one? I tried looking in app settings I do not have any storage account connection strings. Where do you find this? What do you mean by data?

Comment: Are you talking about App Services of Function Apps? Because you don't select a storage account when creating an App Service.

Comment: Both. But now I think I understand what your trying to tell me. So function apps ofcource need to connect to a storage account due to queues etc. And for that I have a Storage Connection. But none of them needs storage account to save the web files and whats needed to host them?

Comment: True. Azure Functions do have a storage account associated with them (although these, too, are connected to with a connection string) because of dashboarding functionality. More information here: [Storage considerations for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations)

Comment: Thanks. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An App Service doesn't *run on* a storage account, it *connects to* a storage account. Which means you can simply switch connection strings. You should, however, think about migrating data as well.

Azure Functions have a storage account associated with them (although these, too, are connected to with a connection string) because of managing triggers and dashboarding functionality.

More information here: [Storage considerations for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations).

> When creating a function app, you must create or link to a general-purpose Azure Storage account that supports Blob, Queue, and Table storage. This is because Functions relies on Azure Storage for operations such as managing triggers and logging function executions.